# TFVC ignoring bin/debug and obj/debug by default

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I noticed that for VS Projects controlled with TFVC, debug folders are ignored naturally without having to create a `.tfignore` file to exclude them. However, I have a legacy project that seems not to follow this behavior and I am unable to fix it because I don't know who's responsible for that behavior in the first place.

Can you explain why debug folders are ignored naturally without having to use a `.tfignore`?

Comment: Do you have different workspaces mapped, perhaps? This sounds like the difference between local and server workspaces.

Comment: Hi Hasan Baidoun，any update on this? Have you tried my solution below?

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT for your answer but it turned out to be something else. I am going to leave an answer to the question for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** The problem turned out to be that - for any reason - the one who added the project to TFS the first time, added the debug and release folders with it - either deliberately or his VS was miss configured - and hence, the VS will keep track of those files even if ignored by default (natural behavior).

In order to solve it, I had to delete those folders form the TFS itself and then get the latest version to get the local copies deleted as well ... later after building the project and having those folders created again, VS will not recognize them as new files/folders because they are ignored by default as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

There are already pre-defined list what files will be excluded by TFS if there is no custom .tfignore specified/present on the system.

You could refer to the "LocalItemExclusions.config" file under the path `"C:\Users\youraccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Configuration\VersionControl" folder and open"`. 
(There may several folders named like 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, you need to make sure open the folder that match your TFS version.)

You could see that these folder and files types are ignored by default and they are defined in that file.

```
      <Exclusion>bin</Exclusion>
      <Exclusion>obj</Exclusion>
      <Exclusion>*.exe</Exclusion>
```

If those files still could not be excluded by default in the legacy project on TFS, as a workaround, you could manually add a `.tfignore` file in that specific project.